Google cloud free credits expiry date
I'm new to Google Cloud Platform (GCP) and recently paid 1000 Indian rupees for a subscription on August 31, 2024. My account shows that the credits will expire in 23 days, which means the end date is listed as September 27, 2024. I was expecting these credits to be valid for 90 days.
Could you clarify why the validity period appears to be shorter than expected? Also, what will happen after September 27, 2024? Will I no longer be able to use GCP services after that date?

You don't need to pay for the free credits. When your free credits expire, your paid credits will kick in. Check your email for details on what you paid the 1000 INR for.
